# how to list unique names in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, col

I want to retrieve in the Pfam_domains column all the names mentioned at least once.

Here is my dataframe:

```
           TCID       Fonction        Genbank Uniprot Pfam_domains
0     3.A.1.1.1           MalE           MalE  P0AEX9      PF00528
1     3.A.1.1.1           MalF           MalF  P02916      PF01547
2     3.A.1.1.1           MalG           MalG  P68183      PF00528
3     3.A.1.1.1           MalK           MalK  P68187      PF00005
4     3.A.1.1.1           MalK           MalK  P68187      PF17912
..          ...            ...            ...     ...          ...
178  3.A.1.5.32  LAC30SC_07295  LAC30SC_07295  F0TFS7      PF00528
179  3.A.1.5.32  LAC30SC_07300  LAC30SC_07300  F0TFS8      PF00528
180  3.A.1.5.32  LAC30SC_07305  LAC30SC_07305  F0TFS9      PF00005
181  3.A.1.5.32  LAC30SC_07305  LAC30SC_07305  F0TFS9      PF08352
182  3.A.1.5.32  LAC30SC_07310  LAC30SC_07310  F0TFT0      PF00005
```

This is my code:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)-1):
    unite=pd.unique(df['Pfam_domains'][i])
```

Here, the problem is that I only list all domains (all occurrences of all domains).

Here is what I would like to have in output:

```
"PF00528"
"PF01547"
"PF00005"
...
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for `df.Pfam_domains.unique()`, no need to iterate over each row

Comment: Or try: `df.Pfam_domains.value_counts()`

Comment: actually, the loop wasn't necessary. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
unite = df['Pfam_domains'].unique()
unite.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

start by sorting the value counts in ascending order:

```py
df.Pfam_domains.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

by definition of a dataframe, this will satisfy your request for values that are "mentioned at least once". if they are in the dataframe - they are mentioned "at least once". If you're actually looking for values that appear MORE than once, then this is also a good starting point.